# a) $\ker B+\operatorname{im}B$ is a direct sum; b) $\ker B+\operatorname{im}B^*$ is a direct sum, where $B^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $B$

Tags: linear-algebra

Define a transformation $B$ on $\mathbb{R}^2 =\{(x,y)\mid x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$ by $B(x,y)=(x-y,x-y)$.

Then which of the following statements is True?

a) $\ker B+\operatorname{im}B$ is a direct sum.

b) $\ker B+\operatorname{im}B^*$ is a direct sum, where $B^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $B$.

My attempts: I know that $\dim\ker B=1$ and $\dim\operatorname{im}B=1$ as $\dim\ker B+\dim\operatorname{im}B=2$.

Here I'm confused how can I check whether it is a direct sum or not...

Any hints/solution will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (a) is equivalent to $\ker B\cap Im\,B=\{0\}$ and (b) is equivalent to $\ker B\cap Im\,B^*=\{0\}$. Are these statements true?

Comment: how $ker B$$ \cap$ Im B = { 0}  ?? im not getting @amsmath

Comment: That's sad. You know that $\ker B$ and $Im B$ are sets and that $\cap$ denotes the intersection of sets?

Comment: yes  i know that  they are set,,

Comment: Do you know how to find  the kernel and image of a linear transformation? Please find the kernel and image. Now check if they are disjoint as sets. At least the first part should be ok.

Comment: So, what is it you don't understand?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг No, (a) is false.

Comment: @amsmath By ok, I mean it should be more doable with the basic principles, than the second part. The first part is false, but thank you for the correction.

Comment: @amsmath...can  u  elaborate  the  option b more ??   as ur  not exaplaining in details......so  i not getting in my mind

Comment: @Messififa Just forget about part 2 for now, and focus about part 1, it is easier. For part 1, you need to find the kernel and image of $B$. Can you find these two sets? Basically, we are trying to understand where *exactly* you need help : of course, you are not getting this question, but we need to know which concept you are lacking or missing : correction of this has far more benefit than just presenting a solution.